# Transfer ColorNote data to new phone without SD card

Tags: backup, data-transfer, notes

I'm trying (without success) to get back my old notes (I changed device). I had an Android Wiko Slim, but I changed for the Android OnePlus, and OnePlus has no external SD card. Instead, it has 64GB internal storage. I don't have the old SD card anyway.

I didn't know about online synchronization and stuff, so I did a raw copy (through USB cable of my old phone) and copied all the folders. I even have most twice, probably one of them being SD Card. So I tried to copy `data/colornote/backup`, replacing my old files. I did the same with `Android/data/com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note` and restarted my phone, but nothing worked.

What is annoying it that I deleted ColorNote folders on my new device before copying them, but I still have my one lonely note I did on my new phone.

Is there a way to do it, like simulate an SD card? Or just replacing manually the right files should do it? Also, which files?

Comment: Related: [Colornote 3.9.82 SD card backup .dat files are not recognized after Android refresh](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128749)