# Colornote 3.9.82 SD card backup .dat files are not recognized after Android refresh

Tags: backup

I backed up all my files on the SD card (Nexus 4) and refreshed my Android.
I then reinstalled Colornote and placed the files (.DAT files) in the same directory (data\colornote\backup), but the files don't show up in Colornote backup.

Now in the [Colornote FAQ](http://www.colornote.com/FAQ.html#collapse6) they talk about 'SD card backup', but this option is not available in the Colornote settings. I use the latest version on Android. I already mailed Colornote about this, but no reply for weeks. 
Does anybody know how I can do the 'SD card backup' in the latest version?

Comment: Did you reboot after copying? Maybe it will help

Comment: **Make sure you've the copy of the notes saved elsewhere before following this comment**. Once you've those .dat files under `/sdcard/data/colornote/backup`, launch Colornote, go to its settings -> Backup and the saved backup should now be listed there. Tap it, choose restore and provide the master password. Doing this will restore the backup and delete the current ones. // Alternatively, if you've the backup of the app itself (some by ADB or some other app), then you can extract the notes from the colornote.db file. Then tell us the final result.

Comment: The problem is I go to Colornote > settings > backup, but the saved backup is not listed... (also after reboot)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! I was missing the .IDX file, so I made one with the same name as my .DAT file. Now I was able to restore my backup. (I also turned off auto backup) Thank you Android gods and Firelord.

PS1: I tried this before but than it didn't work, after reinstalling colornote again it did work. To everybody with Colornote: make backups!